# ggplot2 plotting all values at intersection

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe with two variables that I want to plot against each other

```
Country.Name    Time     Population, total    Total greenhouse gas emissions
Afghanistan     2012     29726803             1.816886e+04

'data.frame':   202 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Country.Name                                         : Factor
 $ Time                                                 : int
 $ Population, total                                    : num
 $ Total greenhouse gas emissions                       : num
```

and I using ggplot 2, but my graph has no scales on either axis and all values are being plotting at the zero intersect.

```
ggplot(data=`Population Vs GHC`,aes(x='Population, total', y='Total greenhouse gas emissions')) + geom_point()
```

[image: output plot]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: The solution, as pointed out by Heroka, was that I was passing a string value and not the column name

Comment: My guess is that you run into problems due to all the spaces in your column names. Try to eleminate them and see if that fixed the problem (they are not practical anyway).

Comment: You are not passing a bare variable name to `aes`, you are passing strings. Use `aes_string` for passing strings as column names.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible (dput some data)